# SSRS Report Manager Parameter defaults

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 and i'm trying to set a Report manager default parameter.

I can set a parameter at run time i.e. '02/03/2006', or assign a drop down boxes via a query but i need it to have a variable date range

I've tried using:
    =getdate()
    getdate()
    now()
    =now()
....the list goes on

Thanks for your help,

Jim

Answer (score 4):

SSRS Report Manager doesn't support using a formula as the default value for a parameter except for when the formula is specified as the default value in the report definition itself.

You should edit the .rdl file in Business Intelligence Development Studio and set the default parameter value there.